# WSO2 APIM 1.10 : I'm getting following exception when i started server

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager

[image: error i got repeatedly in console]

I am using APIM 1.10 and using windows 8.1 using jdk 1.8  whenever i stared the server i got above ERROR

Comment: Never post screenshots of logs. Post logs (text) instead. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the zip you downloaded was corrupted.

So please download it again and try.

Comment: this copy is worked for me early, anyway thanks i'll try again with new copy

Comment: i tried with new copy it wasn't work for me i still get the same error

Comment: did you do any changes to java?

Comment: hi i was able to solve this error by removing java and reinstalling